# VB.net - Adding multiple processes as String

Tags: vb.net

I tried to write a code block which displays all of the pre-declared processes in a MessageBox:

```
 Dim pro As String = "chrome" & "firefox"
    Dim prox() As Process
    Try
        prox = Process.GetProcesses()

        For Each process As Process In prox
            If (pro = process.ProcessName) Then
                MsgBox("Process Found: " & pro & " ,")
            End If
        Next process
```

But whenever I try to match from a list with more than one program, it fails to match any of them. How can I rewrite the code so it can match from a list of processes?

Comment: Where does psList come from?

Comment: Ouh sorry it is prox.... But that doesnt solve the problem

Comment: Yeah, but if you don't show us real code, no one can help you.  Do you really expect a process to be called "chromefirefox"?

Comment: What do you mean with real code? This is the code. I know that "&" is false so that's what I want to know. What can I put there so the programm knows that pro can either be....

Comment: What LarsTech is getting at is that `"chrome" & "firefox"` equals `chromefirefox`.  `&` is used for concatenating strings.

Comment: `If pro.Contains(process.ProcessName) Then`.  It's not clean code though.  I would switch from a string to a list.

Answer (score 0):

In a generic way, and looking into future maintaining and ease of reading you could use this:

```
'use ; as separator, keep one at the beginning and one at the end
Dim pro As String = ";chrome;firefox;iexplorer;safari;etc;"
```

---

Then instead of doing a straight equality test `if pro = processname` do

```
If (pro.Contains(";" & process.ProcessName & ";") Then
```

---

To read you only need to look at two lines (instead of several for an array based solution).

To maintain (add/remove from the list), just update the first line.